# Creating Unlocked Package with Apex class that refers a record type

Tags: custom-field, record-type, unlocked-package

I need suggestions to package an apex class that  references record type.
The record type xml refers to many custom fields which do not belong to that package.
When I package this apex class, I end up moving these custom fields that do not belong to the package. These custom fields are exclusive to a different team and does not require to be shared.

Does anyone has suggestion how to package this Apex class without bringing in all the custom fields referred by the record type ? Thank you

Comment: You can edit your record type to include just the fields you need. Multiple custom objects in different packages can all co-exist in the same org.

Comment: Alternatively consider using an Org Dependent Unlocked Package.

Comment: @sfdcfox you mean the same recordtype xml itself can be partially defined in multiple packages correct?
One challenge we faced recently is that if I define same recordtype in happy-soup and a package, source:deploy command fails with error 
```
 #1 Failed file: objects/Opportunity.object, component: Opportunity.New type: RecordType, problem: Duplicate name 'Opportunity.New' specified, problemType: Error
```

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for the suggestion. My goal is to validate the package in scratch-org  in CICD pipeline. Org dependent package requires the unpackaged metadata to be pre-deployed. I would like to avoid this step

Comment: This should be doable simply using a separate package directory filled with the necessary metadata, as a dependency of the package's package directory.

Comment: @PhilW the trouble with that is not being able to explicitly denote dependencies in org-dependent unlocked packages. Deploying that separate package directory would need to be added to the ci-cd pipeline even though it would only be relevant to this specific org-dependent unlocked package.

Comment: Not sure I really understand why this is problematic.